# JAVA: how to load .png file to JLabel

Tags: java, swing, jframe, png, jlabel

I'm typing my first obiect program - BlackJack, and I have problem with print card image.
My class Card extended JLabel and has ImageIcon property.

```
package Blackjack;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class Card extends JLabel{
    private final String suit, faceName;
    private int cardValue;
    private boolean isVisible = false;
    private BufferedImage cardImage;
    public ImageIcon cardIcon;

public Card(String suit, String faceName){
    this.suit = suit;
    this.faceName = faceName;
    //this.cardImage = getCardImage();
    this.cardIcon = new ImageIcon(getCardImage());

    switch(faceName){
        case "2":
            this.cardValue = 2;
            break;
        case "3":
            this.cardValue = 3;
            break;
        case "4":
            this.cardValue = 4;
            break;
        case "5":
            this.cardValue = 5;
            break;
        case "6":
            this.cardValue = 6;
            break;
        case "7":
            this.cardValue = 7;
            break;
        case "8":
            this.cardValue = 8;
            break;
        case "9":
            this.cardValue = 9;
            break;
        case "10":
            this.cardValue = 10;
            break;
        case "Jack":
            this.cardValue = 10;
            break;
        case "Queen":
            this.cardValue = 10;
            break;
        case "King":
            this.cardValue = 10;
            break;
        case "Ace":
            this.cardValue = 11;
            break;
    }
}

public void setCardVisible(boolean v){
    isVisible = v;
}
public boolean getVisible(){
    return isVisible;
}
public String getCardName(){
    if (isVisible)
        return faceName + " of " + suit;
    else
        return "Karta zakryta";
}
public int getCardValue(){
    if (isVisible)
        return cardValue;
    else
        return 0;
}
public BufferedImage getCardImage(){ //dopisać
    String fileName;
    if (faceName.equals("10"))
        fileName = "T";
    else if (faceName.equals("Jack"))
        fileName = "J";
    else if (faceName.equals("Queen"))
        fileName = "Q";
    else if (faceName.equals("King"))
        fileName = "K";
    else if (faceName.equals("Ace"))
        fileName = "A";
    else
        fileName = faceName;
    fileName = fileName + suit.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase();
    File imgFile = new File("img/" + fileName + ".png");
    try{
        if (isVisible)
            cardImage = ImageIO.read(imgFile);
        else
            cardImage = ImageIO.read(new File("img/RE.png"));
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Blad odczytu obrazka");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Dimension dimension = new Dimension(cardImage.getWidth(), cardImage.getHeight());
    setPreferredSize(dimension);
    return cardImage;
}
}
```

Next class is Table extended JPanel

```
package Blackjack;

import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Table extends JPanel{
    private Deck deck;
    private Player player;
    private Dealer dealer;
    private Hand dealerHand;
    private Hand playerHand;

public Table(Deck d, Dealer dealer, Player player){
    this.deck = d;
    this.deck.shuffleDeck();
    this.dealer = dealer;
    this.player = player;
    this.dealerHand = dealer.getPlayerHand();
    this.playerHand = player.getPlayerHand();

    this.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
}

public Player getPlayer(){
    return player;
}
public Dealer getDealer(){
    return dealer;
}
public Deck getDeck(){
    return deck;
}

}
```

And class Game extended JFrame

```
package Blackjack;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Game extends JFrame{
    private Table table;

public Game(Table t){
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("BlackJack game");
    frame.setSize(800, 500);
    frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    frame.add(t, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}

public static void main (String[] args){
    Deck deck = new Deck();
    Player player = new Player();
    Dealer dealer = new Dealer();

    Table table = new Table (deck, dealer, player);

    player.hitCard(deck.drawCard());
    player.getPlayerHand().getCardsInHand().get(0).setCardVisible(true);
    table.getDealer().hitCard(table.getDeck().drawCard());
    dealer.getPlayerHand().getCardsInHand().get(0).setCardVisible(true);
    player.hitCard(deck.drawCard());
    player.getPlayerHand().getCardsInHand().get(1).setCardVisible(true);
    dealer.hitCard(deck.drawCard());

    table.add(player.getPlayerHand().getCardsInHand().get(0));

    for (Card c : player.getPlayerHand().getCardsInHand())
        System.out.println(c.getCardName());
    for (Card c : dealer.getPlayerHand().getCardsInHand())
        System.out.println(c.getCardName());

Game g = new Game(table);

}
}
```

How should I correctly add card image on my window? Because this

```
table.add(player.getPlayerHand().getCardsInHand().get(0));
```

didn't work... I see only empty green window with JPanels.

Comment: I don't know if it's changed in the latest Java but comparing `String`'s I use `myString.equals(otherString)`. The `==` doesn't work.

Comment: True. But it doesn't change anything in this case. But I corrected code of course.

Comment: It's going to be the same for the switch statement as well in that case.

Comment: "The switch statement compares the String object in its expression with the expressions associated with each case label as if it were using the String.equals method' http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/strings-switch.html

Comment: You are creating the frame and showing it before you finish creating its components. Move `Game g = new Game(table);` to the end.

Comment: Still nothing...

Comment: @Przemek You're correct with the switch statement from JDK 7.

Comment: Other stuff: (1) Start your Swing code on the EDT. (2) Why do you have a `Table table` field when you define one as a local variable? (3) Where are you using the fields of `Card` like its image and value?

Comment: After `Game g = new Game(...)` add `g.setVisible(true);`

Comment: @WLGfx That won't do anything since he is not using `g`, he is creating a new frame. `Game` shouldn't extend `JFrame` anyway the way he did it.

Comment: The `Game` class already extends `JFrame` and in your code you're creating another `JFrame` and displaying that one.

Comment: @WLGfx: When I add `g.setVisible(true);` it shows second empty window.

Comment: @Przemek I already told you where your problem is. Reply to my 3 points.

Comment: Instead of maintaining a seperate icon internally to the `Card`, make sure you are call `setIcon` on the `Card` class when you want to change it

Answer (score 1):

The primary problem is, you never actually set the `icon` property of the `JLabel`, so it has nothing to show

What I would recommend doing, is creating an instance of the face and back image and when the visible state changes, change the `icon` property

```
public class Card extends JLabel {

    private final String suit, faceName;
    private int cardValue;
    private boolean isVisible = false;
    private BufferedImage faceImage;
    private BufferedImage backImage;

    public Card(String suit, String faceName) {
        this.suit = suit;
        this.faceName = faceName;
        this.faceImage = getCardFaceImage();
        backImage = getCardBackImage();

        setCardVisible(false);

        switch (faceName) {
            case "2":
                this.cardValue = 2;
                break;
            case "3":
                this.cardValue = 3;
                break;
            case "4":
                this.cardValue = 4;
                break;
            case "5":
                this.cardValue = 5;
                break;
            case "6":
                this.cardValue = 6;
                break;
            case "7":
                this.cardValue = 7;
                break;
            case "8":
                this.cardValue = 8;
                break;
            case "9":
                this.cardValue = 9;
                break;
            case "10":
                this.cardValue = 10;
                break;
            case "Jack":
                this.cardValue = 10;
                break;
            case "Queen":
                this.cardValue = 10;
                break;
            case "King":
                this.cardValue = 10;
                break;
            case "Ace":
                this.cardValue = 11;
                break;
        }
    }

    public void setCardVisible(boolean v) {
        isVisible = v;
        if (isVisible) {
            setIcon(new ImageIcon(faceImage));
        } else {
            setIcon(new ImageIcon(backImage));
        }
    }

    public boolean isCardVisible() {
        return isVisible;
    }

    public String getCardName() {
        if (isVisible) {
            return faceName + " of " + suit;
        } else {
            return "Karta zakryta";
        }
    }

    public int getCardValue() {
        if (isVisible) {
            return cardValue;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    protected BufferedImage getCardFaceImage() { //dopisać
        String fileName;
        if (faceName.equals("10")) {
            fileName = "T";
        } else if (faceName.equals("Jack")) {
            fileName = "J";
        } else if (faceName.equals("Queen")) {
            fileName = "Q";
        } else if (faceName.equals("King")) {
            fileName = "K";
        } else if (faceName.equals("Ace")) {
            fileName = "A";
        } else {
            fileName = faceName;
        }

        BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(100, 200, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        Graphics2D g2d = img.createGraphics();
        g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
        g2d.fill(new Rectangle(100, 200));
        g2d.dispose();

//            fileName = fileName + suit.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase();
//            File imgFile = new File("img/" + fileName + ".png");
//            try {
//                if (isVisible) {
//                    cardImage = ImageIO.read(imgFile);
//                } else {
//                    cardImage = ImageIO.read(new File("img/RE.png"));
//                }
//            } catch (IOException e) {
//                System.err.println("Blad odczytu obrazka");
//                e.printStackTrace();
//            }
//            Dimension dimension = new Dimension(cardImage.getWidth(), cardImage.getHeight());
//            setPreferredSize(dimension);

        return img;
    }

    protected BufferedImage getCardBackImage() { //dopisać            
        BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(100, 200, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        Graphics2D g2d = img.createGraphics();
        g2d.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g2d.fill(new Rectangle(100, 200));
        g2d.dispose();
        return img;
    }
}
```

You don't need to change the `preferredSize`, the `JLabel` will take care of that itself.

When you change the state of the card's visibility, don't forget to switch the images...

```
public void setCardVisible(boolean v) {
    isVisible = v;
    if (isVisible) {
        setIcon(new ImageIcon(faceImage));
    } else {
        setIcon(new ImageIcon(backImage));
    }
}
```

And don't forget to call this in your constructor, after you've loaded the images ;)

As a general recommendation, instead of dealing with `String` as card name/suits, which allows a lot of possible errors, constraint the values to a small, known group using `enum`

```
public enum CardFace {
    TWO, THREE, FOUR, FIVE, SIX, SEVEN, EIGHT, NINE, JACK, QUEEN, KING, ACE
}

public enum CardSuit {
    HEARTS, DIAMONDS, CLUBS, SPADES
}

public class Card extends JLabel {

    private CardSuit suit;
    private CardFace face;

    //...

    public Card(String CardSuits, CardFace faceName) {
```

While this might seem like a nit pick (and it kind of is), you can expand the `enum`s to do other tasks, for example, you can assign each instance with it's name

```
public enum CardFace {
    TWO("Two"), ...;

    private String name;

    private CardFace(String name) {        
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

}
```

You could even assign the face value to the `enum`...

```
public enum CardFace {
    TWO("Two", 2), ...;

    private String name;
    private int value;

    private CardFace(String name, int value) {        
        this.name = name;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }

}
```

Comment: Its better. Now I see three red rectangles, how can I put there my .png file?

Comment: Instead of creating a `BufferedImage` (and painting), simple load the image files as you were (personally I'd make use of the enums, but that's me)

Comment: Thanks @MadProgrammer, but I don't undarstand. I've never used the g2d class before. I'll start a new, easier project I think.

Comment: You don’t have to, just replace it with the code yet loaded the actual image

Answer (score -1):

Instead of creating another `JFrame` (also pointed out by @user1803551) within the extended class, just set the frame up as this. This will still give you only one window.

```
public class Game extends JFrame{
    private Table table;

public Game(Table t){
    setSize(800, 500);
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    add(t, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    //setVisible(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}

public static void main (String[] args){
    Deck deck = new Deck();
    Player player = new Player();
    Dealer dealer = new Dealer();

    Table table = new Table (deck, dealer, player);

    player.hitCard(deck.drawCard());
    player.getPlayerHand().getCardsInHand().get(0).setCardVisible(true);
    table.getDealer().hitCard(table.getDeck().drawCard());
    dealer.getPlayerHand().getCardsInHand().get(0).setCardVisible(true);
    player.hitCard(deck.drawCard());
    player.getPlayerHand().getCardsInHand().get(1).setCardVisible(true);
    dealer.hitCard(deck.drawCard());

    table.add(player.getPlayerHand().getCardsInHand().get(0));

    for (Card c : player.getPlayerHand().getCardsInHand())
        System.out.println(c.getCardName());
    for (Card c : dealer.getPlayerHand().getCardsInHand())
        System.out.println(c.getCardName());

    Game g = new Game(table);
    //g.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    //g.add(table, BorderLayout.CENTER); // your table
    g.setVisible(true);
}
```

Anything you add to the frame can be done direct from the `Game` class.

EDIT: added the layout and the `Table` (Removed again)

EDIT2:

Within your code I've noticed you do use `System.out.println()` for debug output. Without more information on your output, there's not much else to suggest apart from validating that your images are being loaded correctly, or even the file exists (`File.exists()`) which will show whether the path is correct too. If they load, then output the dimensions of the image and ensure the `JLable` is also set.

My best suggestion would be to use more of the debug output to find where the problem lies. The classes `Deck` and `Dealer` are missing which only leads us to speculate.

Comment: Now you are adding the table twice and also setting a layout for now reason.

Comment: You're dead right. That's because I'm rushing because it is late and I need a bath. (I deserve downvotes for the hasty edits)... I'll try to remedy it before bed.